# Share files and data with external clients

Tags: azure, amazon-s3, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, azure-data-share

We have a use case to share data and some associated files with external clients. Data is stored in data lake(snowflake). We are thinking of storing related files in s3 or azure blob storage. These files are supplementary information/additional attachments to the data.

1. The data is securely served from snowflake.

Is it possible to generate a secure link to the file and serve that along with the data for users to access?

2. Pre signed or SAS URL's will not work because of security concerns.

Is it possible to generate links to files that are easy to open through a browser with b2b type of authentication? Do we need to build a custom function/app to achieve this? Or are there any other options? Did anyone work through a similar use case before?

Comment: Have you considered giving them a Snowflake reader account? https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-sharing-reader-config.html

Comment: @FelipeHoffa, We have the means to share the data through reader accounts. The problem is associating the data with the files in the external storage location.

Comment: There are upcoming features that might be exactly what you need: https://events.snowflake.com/summit/agenda/session/546417?widget=true

Comment: Thank you! I will explore it further!

Answer (score 0):

Moving from comments to an answer for closure:

- There are upcoming features that might be exactly what you need. These features are in private preview now, and official documentation will come soon.
- In the meantime check the presentation at  https://events.snowflake.com/summit/agenda/session/546417?widget=true to learn more.
- I'll update this answer when the features get released and publicly documented.